# How to use Auth and PostgresqlSimple in one handler?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

Alright, so there are a few problems actually, I'll try to describe each of them in isolation of the other, but in a sense they are all related.

I want to insert a user id, which I want to get from the `AuthManager`. Okay that's fair enough, we can just use `currentUser` and then do some `maybe` voodoo to get the actual `unUid`. But then is when the problem starts. Okay, so we want to use `execute` to exute a query:

```
execute "INSERT INTO events(title,recurring) VALUES(?,?);" (eventname,recurring)
```

**boom**. Okay, then when doing `cabal install`, it fails saying that there is no instance of `HasPostgres` available for the type I declared. Makes perfect sense since the type of my handler is `...-> ...-> Handler App (AuthManager App)`. **This is the first problem: I don't know how to correctly make an instance so that the types are correct**. *As I tried, just copying the initial instance in `Application.hs` doesn't help us at all.*

That brings us to other problems that arise when trying to find an alternative solution. So the solutions I tried is by just substituting the `execute` call with a `with pg $ execute` call. This has the following result:

```
Couldn't match type `App' with `AuthManager App'
Expected type: Handler App (AuthManager App) GHC.Int.Int64
  Actual type: Handler App App GHC.Int.Int64
```

So again, to no avail. The next thing I tried is removing `(AuthManager App)` type, and just substituting it by `App`, so then I could replace `AuthManager` calls with `with auth $ call`. Then I realised this isn't the solution either, because once you get `AuthManager` out of there, you need to drop it from every function that calls it.

I need some help with how to fix this. Can I somehow lift the type to fix this? Or alternatively what is a good solution to this problem?

---

**EDIT**

Okay, so I've tried to remove `AuthManager App` out of my type so I can use postgres after all. Now this doesn't go as smoothly either as one would expect. The next part comes from a regular application generated by `Snap init`:

```
handleLoginSubmit :: Handler App App ()
handleLoginSubmit =
with auth $ loginUser "login" "password" Nothing
          (\_ ->handleLogin err) (handleFoo)
where
  err = Just "Unknown user or password"
```

Okay so both `handleLogin`and `handleFoo` now have types `Handler App App ()`, but yet Haskell complains it expects the type `Handler App (AuthManager App) ()`:

```
Couldn't match type `App' with `AuthManager App'
Expected type: Handler App (AuthManager App) ()
  Actual type: Handler App App ()


--Definition of App:
data App = App
{ _heist :: Snaplet (Heist App)
, _sess :: Snaplet SessionManager
, _auth :: Snaplet (AuthManager App)
, _pg   :: Snaplet Postgres
}
```

Comment: What is the signature you are using for your Handlers?

Comment: @DiegoNolan, well typically they have `:: Handler App (AuthManager App) ()`, and then in routes I add `with auth`.

Comment: Have you tried just `Handler App App ()` ?

Comment: @DiegoNolan, yes of course. But then I don't have `Auth` anymore, which is what I need. Then I would have to substitute every `AuthManager` call everywhere where such a handler is called too. It might work but that's what I'm trying to avoid. Also to find a way to avoid 'cascades' in a sense that once you have a type you have to put it everywhere.

Comment: Can't you just do `with auth` when you want to do something for the auth.  This shouldn't be too often.  Likewise you do `with pg` when you want db access. Or you can create an instance of `HasPostgres` then you don't even need to do with `with pg`.  I'm sure something similar can be done with the auth.

Comment: I already don't need to do `with pg` normally, since there is an instance for `Handler b App` but not for `Handler b (AuthManager App)`. Making an instance for `auth` would be a solution as well, if I only knew how to do so. **edit**: on further note it seems like there is no such thing as `hasAuth` or something in the like.

Comment: You would probably have to make your own.  Which is just what `HasPostgres` is.  It just re exports all the Postgresql simple functions to return a monad with a `HasPostgres` instance.  There are aren't many auth functions so this wouldn't take that long probably.  Depends what you want to do. I don't think having all your handlers be `Handler App App ()` and then using `with auth` when needed is that much boilerplate.

Comment: @DiegoNolan, I indeed tried your approach as I agree that it's not too big of an overhead. But yet this doesn't work as expected either, I've updated my question, so see the update.

Comment: can i see your definition of `App`

Comment: @DiegoNolan I've added it to the question. But as far as I know it's standard definition for `App` in Snap init. (except that I had to add `_pg`)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44812/discussion-between-froginvasion-and-diegonolan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use this type signature.

```
yourHandler :: Handler App App ()
    with pg $ execute ...
    with auth $ loginUser ...
```

The `with` function lets you raise a `Handler b v` function, which only has access to the v snaplet's data, into `Handler b b`, which has access to everything.  And the only thing it needs to do that is the lens from b to v.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a snaplet based off the Postgres Snaplet, so this should work for you.

```
instance HasPostgres (Handler App (AuthManager App)) where
     getPostgresState = withTop pg get
```

and then a route with the signature:

```
myRoute :: Handler App (AuthManager App) ()
```